# Bootstrap - Dropdown menu align icon with text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I do not get to align icons with text in dropdown menu. I use the css of the bootstrap framework to do it.

The objective is that the icons are align to the text options in dropdown menu.

Current view:

[image]

Are there any option to center the middle of the icon to the text bottom? I think that this will be the best option.

HTML code:

```
<!-- NAVIGATION -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid"> 
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown marges-opciones-left"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" 
        data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 20px" >face</i> &nbsp; <?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?>&nbsp; <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 20px" >list</i></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="underconstruction.html"><i class="material-icons">settings</i>  Preferències</a></li>
            <li><a href="underconstruction.html"><i class="material-icons">lock</i>  Canviar password</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>   
            <li><a href="logout.php"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:15px">power_settings_new</i>  Log out</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div> 
  </div>
</nav>
```

The CSS code I do not put because is the standard bootstrap css file.

Comment: Check the padding or line height of the icons list <li>Preferencies</li>.

Comment: or share your working demo link or css code

Answer (score 1):

you can use following css:

```
 .dropdown-menu > li > a > i{
        position:relative;
        top:2px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a work around this:

1. Open your CSS File
2. Add the following:

```css
.icorrect {
     padding: 3px; 
     margin-right: 5px;
}
```

3. Add class icorrect to each icon you have issues with. E.g:

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="underconstruction.html"><i class="material-icons icorrect">settings</i>  Preferències</a></li>
```